# Extracting FEW Cell Data from VTK unstructured grids?

Tags: c++, vtk

I extracted the cell data according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897655/vtk-extracting-cell-data-from-vtu-unstructured-grids-in-c) answer.

Everything works fine, but I get only one set of scalar data, however I have two.

```
reader->GetNumberOfScalarsInFile();
```

returns 2, but

```
vtkCellData* cellData = grid->GetCellData();  // grid = reader->GetOutput;
cellData->GetNumberOfArrays();
```

returns 1;

How can I extract second (or more others) set of data?

EDIT:
Here is my vtk file example (it works fine in paraview)

```
# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
Two cubes example
ASCII 
DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID 
POINTS 12 double 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
1.0 0.0 0.0 
1.0 1.0 0.0 
0.0 1.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 1.0 
1.0 0.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
0.0 1.0 1.0
2.0 0.0 0.0
2.0 1.0 0.0
2.0 0.0 1.0
2.0 1.0 1.0
CELLS 2 18
8   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8   1 8 9 2 5 10 11 6
CELL_TYPES 2
12
12
CELL_DATA 2
SCALARS press float 1
LOOKUP_TABLE default
1
2
SCALARS sat float 1
LOOKUP_TABLE default
0.1
0.2
```

[image: CellData in paraview]

Comment: Are you sure the second set is also stored as CellData? Data is often stored at the points. In that case, `grid->GetPointData()` would help. But you'll need to `#include <vtkPointData.h>` for that.

Comment: @RHertel , yes I am sure. I will add my vtk example in my question above

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `SCALARS`, the data at the cells can be stored as `FIELD`s with one component. Then, it can be read with `GetTuple1()`.

```
int main() {
  std::string file = "infile.vtk";
  vtkPointer reader = vtkPointer::New();
  reader->SetFileName(file.c_str());
  reader->Update();
  vtkSmartPointer < vtkDataArray > press = reader->GetOutput()->GetCellData()->GetArray("press");
  vtkSmartPointer < vtkDataArray > sat   = reader->GetOutput()->GetCellData()->GetArray("sat");
  int nc = reader->GetOutput()->GetNumberOfCells();
  std::vector<float> p(nc);
  std::vector<float> s(nc);
  for (int i = 0; i < nc ; ++i) {    
    p[i] =  press->GetTuple1(i) ;
    std::cout<< "p[" << i << "] = "<< p[i] << std::endl;
    s[i] =  sat->GetTuple1(i) ;
    std::cout<< "s[" << i << "] = "<< s[i] << std::endl;
  } 
}
```

This is the file `input.vtk` used in the example:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 5.1
Two cubes example
ASCII 
DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID 
POINTS 12 double 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
1.0 0.0 0.0 
1.0 1.0 0.0 
0.0 1.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 1.0 
1.0 0.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
0.0 1.0 1.0
2.0 0.0 0.0
2.0 1.0 0.0
2.0 0.0 1.0
2.0 1.0 1.0
CELLS 2 18
8   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8   1 8 9 2 5 10 11 6
CELL_TYPES 2
12
12

CELL_DATA 2
FIELD FieldData 2
press 1 2 float 
1
2
sat 1 2 float
0.1
0.2
```